# How do i put variables inside variables - batch

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, replace, find

I want to know how i could set a variable with 2 other variables.

My code:

```
@echo off

set str=the cat and the mouse and the car and the bull and the joker and the batman and some random guy

echo.%str%
set /p find=
set /p replace=
set str=%str:%find%=%replace%%
echo.%str%
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set str=the cat and the mouse and the car and the bull and the joker and the batman and some random guy

echo.%str%
set /p find=
set /p replace=
set str=!str:%find%=%replace%!
echo.%str%
pause
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i was looking for